# analyse intermixed events in splunk

Tags: splunk

My app logs intermixed multiline events like below:

```
05:00:00.123 EventID_1 0 .....
05:00:00.123 EventID_2 0 .....
05:00:00.123 EventID_2 1 .....
05:00:00.124 EventID_1 1 .....
05:00:00.124 EventID_1 2 .....
05:00:00.125 EventID_2 2.....
05:00:00.125 EventID_1 3 .....
05:00:00.125 EventID_3 0 .....
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to group events based on event id.

Comment: my main objective is to list time used for each EventID in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can the [transaction](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.3/SearchReference/Transaction) command.

Such as *`your search`*`| transaction EventID`

Provided your event id is in the field EventID. Then you can use the `duration` field added to give you the time from the first transaction to the last, and `eventcount` for the number of events that are grouped together into a transaction. You can also get fancier with `startswith` and `endswith` if there is another attribute that signifies the start and end of a transaction, and find open transactions (where there is a start but not an end). The `transaction` documentation has more details.

Also look at [this documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.3/Knowledge/Abouttransactions) that mentions "When to use stats instead of transactions", since the `stats` command will help as well, using `by`.

*`your search`*`| stats last(_time) by EventId`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to avoid transaction when you can for performance reasons. It has to maintain a table over the duration of your window, and every event has to be compared to previous events in the table before the search will complete.

An alternate would be to use the stats range() function, like so:

```
[your search] | stats range(_time) as duration by EventID
```

I suggest trying both and observing the performance differences, as well as looking at the job inspector. Over small data sets it may not matter, and the transaction command does give you other features. Over larger data sets this technique using range() will perform much better.